# Convert month name from one language to another without knowing the Culture?

Tags: .net, culture, invariantculture

How can I convert a string with a month name like "agosto" to the english translation "August" without knowing if "agosto" is spanish or italian?

I know that I get the month name for the month number 8 in Spanish with

```
Dim SpanishMonthName as String = Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ES").DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(8)
```

But how can I get the string "August" (8th month name in english) as translation for the spanish or italian month name "agosto"?

Comment: Once you have the number you know how to get "August" from it, so your real question is how to get the month number from a month name when you don't know what language the month name is in, right? Do you have a list of the cultures it could be from?

Comment: @IanMercer Unfortunately, I don't have such list of cultures. At least not one including all possible languages .-)

Comment: `var allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the various `CultureInfo` there are the month names (see `someCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames`), so you could:

```
var italian = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it-IT");
var spanish = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");
var english = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

string month = "agosto";

var italianMonthNames = italian.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;
var spanishMonthNames = spanish.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;

int ix = Array.FindIndex(italianMonthNames, x => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(x, month));
if (ix == -1)
{
    ix = Array.FindIndex(spanishMonthNames, x => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(x, month));
}

// ix is 0 based, while months are 1 based
string englishMonth = ix != -1 ? english.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(ix + 1) : null;
```

You could even try to delegate a little to the .NET `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
var italian = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it-IT");
var spanish = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");
var english = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

string month = "agosto";
string englishMonth = null;
DateTime dt;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(month, "MMMM", italian, 0, out dt) || DateTime.TryParseExact(month, "MMMM", spanish, 0, out dt))
{
    englishMonth = dt.ToString("MMMM", english);
}
```

In general there is at least one month that has a different meaning in two languages: *listopad* (October or November, see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FalseFriends/comments/20r8e3/ff_listopad_is_the_month_of_november_in_both/)). The full list is *Hlakola, listopad, Mopitlo, Nhlangula, Nyakanga, Phupu*

A first version that uses a `Dictionary<>` to collect month names:

```
public class MonthNameFinder
{
    private readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> MonthToNumber;

    public MonthNameFinder(params string[] cultures)
    {
        MonthToNumber = BuildDictionary(cultures.Select(x => CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(x)));
    }

    public MonthNameFinder(params CultureInfo[] cultureInfos)
    {
        MonthToNumber = BuildDictionary(cultureInfos);
    }

    public MonthNameFinder(CultureTypes cultureTypes = CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    {
        MonthToNumber = BuildDictionary(CultureInfo.GetCultures(cultureTypes));
    }

    private static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> BuildDictionary(IEnumerable<CultureInfo> cultureInfos)
    {
        // Note that the comparer will always be wrong, sadly. Each culture has its comparer
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        foreach (var culture in cultureInfos)
        {
            var monthNames = culture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;

            for (int i = 0; i < monthNames.Length; i++)
            {
                string monthName = monthNames[i];

                int other;

                if (!dict.TryGetValue(monthName, out other))
                {
                    dict[monthName] = i + 1;
                }
                else if (other != i + 1)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Repeated month {monthName}: {i + 1} in {culture.Name} ({culture.DisplayName})");
                }
            }
        }

        return dict;
    }

    public int? GetMonthNumber(string monthName)
    {
        int monthNumber;

        if (MonthToNumber.TryGetValue(monthName, out monthNumber))
        {
            return monthNumber;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

use it like:

```
var mnf = new MonthNameFinder();
int? n = mnf.GetMonthNumber("agosto");

if (n != null)
{
    string name = new DateTime(1, n.Value, 1).ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
}
```

(note that you should cache `mnf`... it is probably quite expensive to build)

Mmmh... I don't like it... I'm a little OC... and the simple fact that I know that there are some collisions in the name of the months is bothering me.

Here is a second version, using a `ILookup<>` and saving even the `CultureName`, so that it is possible to discover the language(s) of the month name. The
`GetMonthNumbers(monthName)` now returns a `(int MonthNumber, string CultureName)[]`, an array of anonymous valuet types. You can clearly take the first one and live happily, or you can check it to see if there are multiple different `MonthNumber`s.

```
public class MonthNameFinder
{
    private readonly ILookup<string, (int MonthNumber, string CultureName)> MonthToNumber;

    public MonthNameFinder(params string[] cultures)
    {
        MonthToNumber = BuildLookup(cultures.Select(x => CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(x)));
    }

    public MonthNameFinder(params CultureInfo[] cultureInfos)
    {
        MonthToNumber = BuildLookup(cultureInfos);
    }

    public MonthNameFinder(CultureTypes cultureTypes = CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    {
        MonthToNumber = BuildLookup(CultureInfo.GetCultures(cultureTypes));
    }

    private static ILookup<string, (int MonthNumber, string CultureName)> BuildLookup(IEnumerable<CultureInfo> cultureInfos)
    {
        // Note that the comparer will always be wrong, sadly. Each culture has its comparer
        var lst = new List<(string Name, int MonthNumber, string CultureName)>();

        foreach (var culture in cultureInfos)
        {
            var monthNames = culture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;

            for (int i = 0; i < monthNames.Length; i++)
            {
                string monthName = monthNames[i];
                lst.Add((monthName, i + 1, culture.Name));
            }
        }

        return lst.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .ThenBy(x => x.MonthNumber)
            .ToLookup(x => x.Name, x => (x.MonthNumber, x.CultureName), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public (int MonthNumber, string CultureName)[] GetMonthNumbers(string monthName)
    {
        return MonthToNumber[monthName].ToArray();
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
// This is an array of (MonthNumber, CultureName)
var mnf = new MonthNameFinder();

var numbers = mnf.GetMonthNumbers("agosto");

if (numbers.Length != 0)
{
    string monthName = new DateTime(1, numbers[0].MonthNumber, 1).ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
}
```

(even here you should cache `mnf`... it is probably quite expensive to build)

Note that there are many similar cultures, so `numbers` will be quite big (for example just for Italian there are 5 cultures, and a search for *agosto* returned 52 different cultures with the month *agosto*.

Comment: Whoa, `Array.FindIndex` twice sounds inefficient. Why not just `Array.Find()`?

Comment: You probably meant `Array.IndexOf`.... With `Array.Find` if I look for _Agosto_ it will return _Agosto_ ... `Array.IndexOf` doesn't support ignore case comparers. If a performant solution is wanted, it is possible to cache the month names in a dictionary. But it becomes more complex.

Comment: OK. But why not cache the result in a local?

Comment: @Charlieface Because that's not what's being asked in the question?

Comment: @Charlieface The second `Array.FindIndex` is done if the first failed, and is done on **spanish** month names, while the first is done on **italian** month names

Comment: Whoops sorry, my bad

Comment: @xanatos Your second example works great and seems to be easier to understand (for me). I assume, there is no way to tell .NET to try all CulturInfo without defining them first for every language individually with "xx-YY"? Just for the case that "agosto" is portuguese? .-)

Comment: @PeterCo Yes, it is possible, but as I've written in the code, there are some name collisions... _listopad_ for example. A full list of collisions is: Hlakola, listopad, Mopitlo, Nhlangula, Nyakanga, Phupu

Comment: @xanatos I think I could live with that. As well as the fact that there are Cultures with 13 months, leap months and so on...